# PayPal Custom variable returned back

Tags: api, paypal

I am new to PayPal API, so I have a nooby question.

When I send user from my shopping site to PayPal payment page e.g. https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_s-xclick&hosted_button_id=xxxxxx&custom=xxxx and I use custom variable with unique ID about product inside my database and when user get returned back to my website thank you page, do I use simple `$_GET["custom"]` inside my php script to grab that value or I need some PayPal API code implemented inside my website?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to retrieve this value, you would not be able to get it as you described, however, you can do one of a couple of things:

1. post the custom value to a cookie or session variable before sending the user to paypal, then retrieving the cookie or session variable value when they are returned from paypal.
2. (preferred method) implement an IPN listener that will be able to parse the posted transaction details, one of which is the custom value.  This method would allow you to confirm a completed transaction as well as do pretty much anything else with the data that you need to do.

Paypal has PHP code samples for an IPN listener on their DEV site.  It's pretty easy to implement and follow along.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brendan. 

So by adding PHP Code sample from this page https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623 I will be able to grab Custom variable value? Of course I need to assign custom variables to local variables at the end of code.

Comment: can you please confirm this?

Comment: I would recommend looking at this link: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/

If you've never implemented IPNs before, you will want to have a better understanding of how they can be used, but also how you have to change your paypal settings to use them.

In answer to your question, though, by using the PHP sample, a message will be posted to your IPN listener and returned to Paypal confirming receipt of the message.  You can then have the page do whatever you program it to do with the data sent by paypal.

Comment: For example, my IPN listener checks the TXN_TYPE variable to see which one of my transaction databases needs to be updated.  I have different databases for API transactions, Instant transactions, and PayPal Here transactions. My business needs them to be separate and the IPN listener handles that for me and then sends me an email letting me know that it's done so.  Again, I've programmed it to do all of that, but the basic IPN code came from the Paypal Dev Site.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread I know but if I understand the user correctly and he is using the IPN url to collect the returned data he can use $myphpvar = $_POST[custom];

More info @ http://www.brianmoreau.com/articles/paypal_buy_now_button_sending_custom_variables.php